# using histogram counts in scatter

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

this my code to  and i want to use histogram data to plot scatter where y axis is counts center from the histogram,is there any direct command or way to do this?

```
from pylab import*
import scipy.stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy
r= numpy.random.uniform(0.0 ,1.0, 4000)
x=norm.rvs(5., 0.5,size=4000)
p=norm.rvs(2000. , 100. ,size=4000)
tau=.894*(10**-10)
m=497.7
c=3.0*(10**10)
E=(p*p + m*m)**.5
beta = p/E
gamma = (1-beta*beta)**(-0.5)
t= - tau * log (r)
T= t*gamma
g=beta*T*c
w= x+g
l=ma.masked_where(w<10.0,w)
l1=ma.masked_where(l>40.,l)
t1=ma.masked_where(w>40.,t)
t2=ma.masked_where(w<10.,t1)
A=hist(t2.compressed()*10**10)
pos=A[1][:-1]+(A[1][1]-A[1][0])/2.0
scatter(pos,A[0])
#########want to use center of counts in scatter as y axis , (A[0]=counts )
#x=t2.compressed()*10**10)
####y=????
#scatter(x,y)
```

This generates

[image]

Comment: This code does not run: there are syntax errors and undefined variables. Can you edit it so that it runs as-is?

Comment: yes there's one capital x ...it should run by now...

Comment: It still doesn't run - first error is the line containing `(-o.5)`. It's better to actually check that it runs, rather than assuming. You can either paste this straight into an interpreter or run it as a script. You can then fix all the errors and then update the question.

Comment: OK great, it now runs without problems and I can call `show()`, which displays the figure. I added it to the question for illustration. Can you explain in more detail what you want to change? I am having trouble understanding exactly what you mean by using the "center of counts in scatter as y axis ".

Comment: Do you just want the same plot but without the histogram bars?

Comment: yes this is what i want

Comment: Me E thank you for taking time to look at my question,i want the scatter between (t2.compressed()*10**10) as x , and number of occurrences as y..which i should get it from the histogram..

Comment: Then why do you plot the histogram instead of only calculating it? You can use `alpha=0` for quick & dirty, but it wouldnt make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
from pylab import *
```

you have imported `matplotlib`'s [hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) function. This both calculated the histogram AND plots it. From the comments I gather you essentially want to remove the histogram from your plot? If so then simply replace

```
A=hist(t2.compressed()*10**10)
```

with

```
A = numpy.histogram(t2.compressed()*10**10)
```

This was you only calculate the histogram and don't plot it (`A` is exactly the same return as `hist` also calls `numpy.histogram`.

**EDIT:**

More generally you can automate this with a function such as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def BinnedScatterPlot(x, **args):
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, **args)
    bin_centers = .5*(bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])
    plt.scatter(bin_centers, hist)
    plt.show()

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=1000)
BinnedScatterPlot(x, bins=20)
```